# Core OWASP ModSecurity - Allowing JSON

Tags: json, content-type, owasp, mod-security

I've had ModSecurity and the Core OWASP Rule Set ver.2.2.5 installed for some months now, but a JSON endpoint on the site has recently stopped responding, and the Apache log gets the following:

> [Tue Jul 21 10:41:12 2015] [error] [client 194.54.11.146] ModSecurity:
>   Warning. Match of "streq %{SESSION.IP_HASH}" against "TX:ip_hash"
>   required. [file
>   "/etc/modsecurity/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_16_session_hijacking.conf"]
>   [line "35"] [id "981059"] [msg "Warning - Sticky SessionID Data
>   Changed - IP Address Mismatch."] [hostname "************"] [uri
>   "/api/campaigns/d3c735cb-0773-11e4-98bd-02f651afdab5"] [unique_id
>   "Va4hyKwfKiYAAAYSLigAAAAJ"]
>
> [Tue Jul 21 10:41:12 2015] [error] [client 194.54.11.146] ModSecurity:
>   Warning. Match of "streq %{SESSION.UA_HASH}" against "TX:ua_hash"
>   required. [file
>   "/etc/modsecurity/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_16_session_hijacking.conf"]
>   [line "36"] [id "981060"] [msg "Warning - Sticky SessionID Data
>   Changed - User-Agent Mismatch."] [hostname "************"] [uri
>   "/api/campaigns/d3c735cb-0773-11e4-98bd-02f651afdab5"] [unique_id
>   "Va4hyKwfKiYAAAYSLigAAAAJ"]
>
> [Tue Jul 21 10:41:12 2015] [error] [client 194.54.11.146] ModSecurity:
>   Warning. Operator EQ matched 2 at TX:sticky_session_anomaly. [file
>   "/etc/modsecurity/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_16_session_hijacking.conf"]
>   [line "37"] [id "981061"] [msg "Possible Session Hijacking - IP
>   Address and User-Agent Mismatch."] [hostname "************"] [uri
>   "/api/campaigns/d3c735cb-0773-11e4-98bd-02f651afdab5"] [unique_id
>   "Va4hyKwfKiYAAAYSLigAAAAJ"]
>
> [Tue Jul 21 10:41:12 2015] [error] [client 194.54.11.146] ModSecurity:
>   Warning. Match of "rx ^%{tx.allowed_request_content_type}$" against
>   "TX:0" required. [file
>   "/etc/modsecurity/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_30_http_policy.conf"]
>   [line "64"] [id "960010"] [msg "Request content type is not allowed by
>   policy"] [data "application/json"] [severity "WARNING"] [tag
>   "POLICY/ENCODING_NOT_ALLOWED"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-20"] [tag
>   "OWASP_TOP_10/A1"] [tag "OWASP_AppSensor/EE2"] [tag "PCI/12.1"]
>   [hostname "************"] [uri
>   "/api/campaigns/d3c735cb-0773-11e4-98bd-02f651afdab5"] [unique_id
>   "Va4hyKwfKiYAAAYSLigAAAAJ"]

I'm new to mod_security and the OWASP rules (I basically followed the guide [here](http://blog.mattbrock.co.uk/hardening-the-security-on-ubuntu-server-14-04/)) but as I understand, rules are scored, and if a request passes a threshold, it's nuked. I assume this is what I'm seeing here.

The final one is the one that concerns me - "application/json" should certainly be allowed. From looking at `/etc/modsecurity/modsecurity_crs_10_setup.conf`, I see:

```
setvar:'tx.allowed_request_content_type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded|multipart/form-data|text/xml|application/xml|application/x-amf'
```

My question is:
1. Can I just add application/json in here to make the error go away?
2. Is that the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can so it reads like this:

```
setvar:'tx.allowed_request_content_type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded|multipart/form-data|text/xml|application/xml|application/x-amf|application/json'
```

Yes that is the correct way of doing this.

Comment: After updating to ruleset ver.2.2.9 I had to add `text/plain` there too. For some reason it worked fine with ver.2.2.6